# Plot events between sampling start and sampling end

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data from various `recording`s indicating the `time` an event happened. I'd like to get a sense of whether these `time` points become more or less 'dense' during the sampling windows. For each `recording` I know when the sampling window opens (`sample_start`) and closes (`sample_end`). But I do not know how to incorporate these time windows into the plot. Instead, the `time` scales range from the first observed event to the last observed event:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%

  # shorten labels for `recording`:
  mutate(recording = str_remove(recording, "^.+?_.+?_")) %>%
  
  # create starttime and endtime of events:
  mutate(Starttime_ms = log(time),
         Endtime_ms = log(time) + 0.01) %>%
  
  # plot:
  ggplot(aes(x = Starttime_ms, xend = Endtime_ms,
             y = recording, yend = recording,
             color = setting
  )) +
  
  # draw segments:
  geom_segment(size = 7) +
  
  # use facets:
  facet_wrap(~ recording, scales = "free_x", 
             ncol = 2)+

  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**How can for each `recording` the time window indicated in columns `sample_start` and `sample_end` be incorporated into the plot?**

[image]

**Data** (edited):

```
df <- structure(list(recording = c("PECII_PL_Car_20210724", "PECII_PL_Car_20210724", 
"PECII_PL_Car_20210724", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", 
"PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", 
"PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Car_20210607", 
"PECII_PL_Car_20210607", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", 
"PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", 
"PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", 
"PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", 
"PECII_PL_Brkfst_20220703", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", 
"PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", 
"PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", 
"PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", 
"PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", "PECII_PL_Game_20220707", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", "PECII_DE_Car_20160924", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", 
"PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Car_20171031_1", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20151113", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Game_20211103", 
"PECII_DE_Game_20211103", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20161025", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", 
"PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", "PECII_DE_Brkfst_20160213", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20220327", "PECII_IT_Car_20220327", "PECII_IT_Car_20220327", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20220327", "PECII_IT_Car_20220327", "PECII_IT_Car_20220327", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", 
"PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", "PECII_IT_Car_20160720", 
"PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", 
"PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", 
"PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", 
"PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", 
"PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", "PECII_IT_Game_20210726", 
"PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", 
"PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", 
"PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", "PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729", 
"PECII_IT_Brkfst_20210729"), time = c(299915L, 305950L, 414950L, 
367211L, 368763L, 859785L, 992532L, 1778677L, 1795244L, 1843270L, 
1895460L, 1898543L, 1765310L, 1780940L, 2078415L, 2454645L, 2562760L, 
2645170L, 2651320L, 2658010L, 2917690L, 2923135L, 2924780L, 2927841L, 
1990025L, 2016883L, 2107474L, 2121066L, 2168096L, 2192847L, 2320129L, 
2413563L, 2447052L, 2528805L, 2547761L, 2939699L, 3142276L, 3145813L, 
229405L, 516918L, 544703L, 2150852L, 2472854L, 2561759L, 3036890L, 
3161999L, 3176270L, 136249L, 324244L, 433471L, 442320L, 483069L, 
518368L, 1853809L, 1878207L, 2288670L, 2326090L, 2333598L, 774829L, 
803126L, 998004L, 1125324L, 1242183L, 1606054L, 1636446L, 1809308L, 
1852619L, 1900553L, 2314462L, 2529171L, 2640496L, 2862360L, 3150111L, 
495890L, 580040L, 582880L, 583515L, 598263L, 639467L, 991005L, 
1392617L, 1621957L, 1624635L, 2133469L, 2196388L, 2286699L, 2421000L, 
783963L, 839886L, 862204L, 879443L, 980761L, 1106613L, 1531772L, 
1541533L, 1568408L, 1573431L, 1633113L, 1642761L, 195015L, 232009L, 
253045L, 371703L, 444946L, 499634L, 1008928L, 1051858L, 1302978L, 
1335671L, 1490043L, 1627051L, 1933254L, 2341028L, 186152L, 187519L, 
693341L, 744425L, 888961L, 2322511L, 2492110L, 2827269L, 2864468L, 
2973513L, 4767243L, 6472499L, 6514817L, 6569297L, 6621823L, 6627898L, 
6722647L, 6730885L, 6794678L, 6796764L, 6799105L, 740415L, 828366L, 
830149L, 852016L, 995265L, 1086965L, 1244390L, 1246345L, 1332666L, 
1466466L, 1605782L, 1701232L, 2069424L, 2092440L, 2131149L, 776770L, 
800130L, 1207700L, 1237250L, 1350140L, 1552420L, 1655680L, 1823290L, 
1840567L, 1850970L), sample_start = c(184850L, 184850L, 184850L, 
16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 16965L, 
16965L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 
1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1699690L, 1894344L, 
1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 
1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 1894344L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 
600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 600014L, 
600014L, 600014L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 
209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 209000L, 
209000L, 209000L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 
664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 664238L, 
178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 
178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 178020L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 
2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 
2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 2479820L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 
740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 
740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 740415L, 419990L, 419990L, 
419990L, 419990L, 419990L, 419990L, 419990L, 419990L, 419990L, 
419990L), setting = c("Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", "Car", 
"Car", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", "Game", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst", 
"Brkfst", "Brkfst", "Brkfst"), sample_end = c(1320055L, 1320055L, 
1320055L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 
2068089L, 2068089L, 2068089L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 
2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 2928880L, 
2928880L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 
3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 3145721L, 
3145721L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 
3891074L, 3891074L, 3891074L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 
2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 2330030L, 
3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 
3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 3161313L, 
3161313L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 
2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 2425163L, 
2425163L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 
1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 1650063L, 2346168L, 
2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 
2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2346168L, 2446240L, 
2446240L, 2446240L, 2446240L, 2446240L, 2446240L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 
6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 
6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 6802270L, 2138141L, 
2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 
2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 2138141L, 
1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L, 
1875120L, 1875120L, 1875120L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-159L))
```

Comment: Do you want the specific values of sample_start and sample_end to be noted in the respective facets' x axes, or just have the axes aligned with those?

Comment: just have the axes aligned with those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach where I add the sample_start and sample_end values as a layer, which makes each facet aligned similarly to its respective range.

You have a few options for how to show which ranges have more frequency. One nice option is a "swarm" plot, which like `geom_jitter` will separate overlapping points, but with the added benefit that it can indicate higher local density by jittering farther from the axis. I haven't tweaked for the best settings here, but hopefully this indicates a possibility.

```
df |>
  ggplot(aes(time, 0)) +
  ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom(groupOnX = FALSE, bandwidth = 0.1) +
  geom_point(data = df |> 
               distinct(recording, sample_start, sample_end) |>
               pivot_longer(sample_start:sample_end, values_to = "time"),
             color = "red", alpha = 0.2) + # make alpha = 0 to hide
  facet_wrap(~recording, ncol = 3, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Throws this error: `Error in facet_wrap(~recording, n_col = 3, scales = "free_x") : 
  unused argument (n_col = 3)`

Comment: My typo - meant `ncol`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: plot a rectangle in the background that shows the sampling period in each facet.

The code below uses `geom_rect()` to do this.  Since the grain of the original `df` is one row per sample, I fed a new dataframe into `geom_rect()` that's one row per facet.  (If we don't do this, the code will still run, but the sampling window will be plotted once for very sample, and the facets with more samples will have darker rectangles - not what we want.)

```
with(
  list(df = df %>%
         mutate(recording = str_remove(recording, "^.+?_.+?_"),
                Starttime_ms = log(time),
                Endtime_ms = log(time) + 0.01,
                setting = gsub("_.*", "", recording))),
  df %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_rect(data = df %>%
                dplyr::select(setting, recording, sample_start, sample_end) %>%
                distinct(),
              aes(xmin = log(sample_start), xmax = log(sample_end),
                  ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf),
              color = NA, fill = "gray", alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = Starttime_ms, xend = Endtime_ms,
                     y = 0, yend = 0, color = setting),
                 size = 7) +
    facet_wrap(~ recording, ncol = 2) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")
)
```

[image]

A few other minor changes to the code above, any of which you may or may not want to keep:

- To avoid having to `mutate()` the columns of `df` again in the argument to `geom_rect()`, I wrapped the whole thing in a `with` and applied the changes just once.
- I moved the mappings for `geom_segment()` from the main `ggplot()` to `geom_segment()` itself, in order to avoid interference with the mappings for `geom_rect()`.
- I set the y limits of each rectangle to negative and positive infinity, to guarantee that the rectangle would fill the entire vertical space.  To make this work, I changed the mapping of `y` and `yend` to 0 instead of `recording`.
- I changed the theme to `theme_bw` to make the gray rectangle stand out more clearly.
- I added a field `setting` that takes the first part of each `recording` - the code above didn't explicitly do this, but it seems to be necessary in order to reproduce the original plot.
- Almost all of the observations in the provided dataset are in fact within the sampling period.  I removed `scales = "free_x"` from `facet_wrap()` to make it clearer that the rectangles are different in each facet.  Adding back `scales = "free_x"` lets the events within each facet stand out more clearly but obscures the differences between facets; here's what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Clever, but visually suboptimal as many events are invisible.

Comment: I think it's just because the whole time span is very large and events close to each other appear to be squashed together.  Adding `scales = "free_x"` lets the events in each facet show up more clearly (but obscures the differences between facets); I'll edit the post to show this.